# Read a row by row from csv file

Tags: java, android

I have CSV file it contains users time, distance, latitude and longitude other details, i click start button  read row by row every 5 seconds and if click pause button it need to pause reading and if i click start again continue from where it paused. Now it displaying all rows.

```
public class CurrnetActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_currnet);
    initViews();
}

public void initViews() {

    InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.athlete_run);
    CSVReader csvFile = new CSVReader(inputStream);
    final List<String[]> Row = csvFile.read();

    final Handler handlerOne = new Handler();
    Runnable runnableOne = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            for (int i = 0; i < Row.size(); i++) {

                Log.i("===dsd", Row.get(i)[0]);
  //Log.d(Constants.TAG, String.format("row %s: %s, %s", i, rows.get(i)[0], rows.get(i)[1]));

            }
            handlerOne.postDelayed(this, 2000);

        }
    };

    handlerOne.postDelayed(runnableOne, 2000);
}

}
```

CSV READER class

```
public class CSVReader {
InputStream inputStream;

public CSVReader(InputStream inputStream){
    this.inputStream = inputStream;
}

public List<String[]> read(){
    List<String[]> resultList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    try {
        String csvLine;
        while ((csvLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] row = csvLine.split(",");
            resultList.add(row);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error in reading CSV file: "+ex);
    }
    finally {
        try {
            inputStream.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error while closing input stream: "+e);
        }
    }
    return resultList;
}
}
```

Comment: can you doublecheck your csv file? is it separated with ',' or ';'?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @patrickChen unable to read row by row with time dealy

Comment: @LokeshGPLoki, based on your code, you read all the lines into memory, you want to change this part to `read and pause`?

Comment: @PatrickChen Yes, but i want  read row by row and pause

Comment: @LokeshGPLoki, you could read in another thread and call `Thread.wait()` when it gets the pause signal, restart if it gets notified.

Answer (score 0):

I got the exact same result when I tested your example with the following csv file:

```
Username; Identifier;First name;Last name
booker12;9012;Rachel;Booker
grey07;2070;Laura;Grey
johnson81;4081;Craig;Johnson
jenkins46;9346;Mary;Jenkins
smith79;5079;Jamie;Smith
```

However, when I changed `String[] row = csvLine.split(",");` to `String[] row = csvLine.split(";");` in `CSVReader` class it worked.

Seems like your csv file values are not separated with a comma. You were looking for a comma to separate each value, so the whole line is red as a single value.

The csv format is not standardized. According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) also semicolons, tabs or spaces are used as separation.
It is important to check your csv file for the seperator. Maybe you need to change line `String[] row = csvLine.split(",");` to different separator.

Comment: unable get result in csv  it contails split with ", "

Comment: Thank you for your response. i done with another method